# Multiple ColumnSeries in Amcharts Horizontally stacked axes are not filling in available space

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to create Horizontally stacked axes using multiple ColumnSeries based on this example. https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v4/horizontally-stacked-axes-v4

Instead of a two-line series and one column series, I am trying to create all three as column series. When I create three-column series, the result is similar to below.

[image]

So column is filling in only one-third of the available space for each of the column series. I expect it to fill in similar to the column when one column and two-line series are used.

How to make all the three-column series to use the entire space and in the same alignment ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `ColumnSeries.clusterd=true` to make columns overlap with other series.

In this example, add the following lines:

```
series1.clustered = false;
series2.clustered = false;
series3.clustered = false;
```

See document: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/columnseries/#clustered_property